# Slowly scaling Rect (pygame)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am building a Star Fox like game. The player needs to control a ship in order to move trough gaps in the walls. Here are my problems:

1. I need to somehow detect collision with wall (if any)
2. How do I make the wall (Rect) slowly get bigger until it reaches a point?

[Full code](https://github.com/xslendix/StarNox)

If the solution can be done with classes, that would be great!

Comment: your code link gives a 404 error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation for the `pygame.Rect` class: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate

To detect collision, the `pygame.Rect` class has methods to detect collision between `Rect`s. There are a few there, so you could use `collidelist()` to check if the player's ship's `Rect` collides with any of the wall `Rect`s.

The class also has two methods `inflate()` and `inflate_ip` which can be used to increase the size of any `Rect`s.